# Como setar a primeira posição da lista em Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Observem a imagem;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você percebe que a primeira posição da lista está sendo indicado com a seta, como eu faço que toda vez que for carregado o formulário ele carregar com a primeira posição da lista?

Esse é meu HTML;

```
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"><fmt:message key="label.sagresPessoal.tela.prestacao.unidade.jurisdicionada" /></label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
       <select id="idUJ" name="prestacaoFolha.idUnidadeGestora" class="form-control select2 ">
            <option value ="">-</option>
                <c:forEach items="${listPessoaJuridica}" var="PJ">
                    <option value="${fn:replace(PJ.codigo,'.','')}">${PJ.nome}</option>
               </c:forEach>
        </select>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Eu tentei dessa forma, porém não funcionou!;

```
$("#idUJ option:first").attr('selected','selected');
```

Por favor, como eu poderia fazer?

Estou utilizando esse Javascript;

```
function justificarRemessa() {
    $('#idUJ').val();
    alert($('#idUJ').val());
    $('#idPeriodoInicio').val("");
    $('#idMotivo').val("");
    $('#idPeriodoFim').val("");
    $('#modalJustificar').modal('show');
}
```

Comment: Qual é o componente que está usando para montar a busca? Aliás... porque você precisa do primeiro `<option value ="">-</option>`?

Comment: Você quis dizer o SEGUNDO item da lista? Porque pelo código este selecionado é o primeiro.

Comment: É o primeiro item da lista que está em branco!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para selecionar o SEGUNDO item da lista (visto que o primeiro é o "-"), use:

```js
$('#idUJ option:eq(1)').prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: esse não pegou, infelizmente :(

Comment: Não? Neste teste que fiz deu certo: https://jsfiddle.net/dbvz8usq/

Comment: Eu colocou como solução correta, mas eu esqueci de mencionar que meu formulário é um modal, e para limpar deve ser um pouco diferente, é por isso que no meu caso não deu certo pelo fato do meu formulário ser um modal.

Answer (score 0):

Para o `select2()` você pode setar o valor da sua option e disaparar o evento de change.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('#idUJ').select2();
 
 //seleciona o valor da posição desejada
 let valor =  $("#idUJ option:eq(1)").val()
 
 //seleciona no select2 e disapara o evento
 $('#idUJ').val(valor).trigger('change');
 
});
```

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css';
@import 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css';
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"><fmt:message key="label.sagresPessoal.tela.prestacao.unidade.jurisdicionada" /></label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <select id="idUJ" name="prestacaoFolha.idUnidadeGestora" class="form-control select2 ">
      <option value="">-</option>
      <option value="a">Empresa 1</option>
      <option value="b">Empresa 2</option>
      <option value="c">Empresa 3</option>

    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Esse não pegou.

Comment: Não pegou o que?